# Как избавиться от System.AccessViolationException, возникающего в ReadProcessMemory?

Tags: c#

Я пытаюсь прочесть значение, записанное в области памяти по адресу 1AD98845170. Там лежит символ 'd', соответственно значение, записанное в этой области - это 64. Эту информацию я взял из Cheat Engine. Прочесть эту же область памяти в моём приложении на C# я не могу. Оно падает с исключением System.AccessViolationException. В качестве процесса выступает стандартный Блокнот Windows 10.

P.S.: На англоязычном stack'е ссылались на топик: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431860/how-to-use-readprocessmemory , но он мне не помог.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, Int64 lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];
        IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(0x0010, false, process.Id);
        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[12];
        ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, 0x1AD98845170, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead); // problem is here
        string res = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer) + " (" + bytesRead.ToString() + "bytes)";
        textBox.Text = res.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Вы не можете получить доступ к памяти другого процесса, операционная система не позволит, если только сами его не запустите из своего приложения как дочерний процесс.

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема в разрядности. У вас объявление ReadProcessMemory как для 64-разрядного процесса, а сама программа, видимо 32-разрядная, отсюда и падение. По ссылке как раз пример рабочий для 32-разрядного, но вам он не поможет, так как 0x1AD98845170 - больше, чем 32-разрядное адресное пространство может переварить.

Comment: @aepot Это не так. В Windows, например, отношение "родительский - дочерний процесс" вообще никак не влияет на права доступа. Программа может свободно читать память любого процесса, который запущен от имени того же пользователя, а при наличии Debug Privilege - любого пользователя (кроме защищенных процессов). Кроме того, у автора проверка ошибок вообще не реализована, поэтому он бы не узнал о недостатке прав (AccessViolationException генерируется не из-за него, а из-за ошибочной сигнатуры P/Invoke).

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight спасибо, я действительно ошибся.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Вы сделали верное предположение. Моя программа запускалась как 32-разрядная. Я отключил в настройках сборки параметр "Предпочтительна 32-разрядная версия" и всё заработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReadProcessMemory объявлена для 64-разрядного процесса, а сама программа, была 32-разрядная, отсюда и падение. По ссылке находится рабочий пример для 32-разрядного процесса, но он бы всё равно не помог, так как адрес 0x1AD98845170 не подходит для 32-разрядного адресного пространства.